# Using ServiceStack MiniProfiler to profile all service client calls

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

Context: I'm writing a service using ServiceStack. This service is calling some other remote services (using the ServiceStack `JsonServiceClient`).

Requirement: show every call to the remote service as a step in MiniProfiler.

Question: what would be the best way to implement this in a generic way?

---

The original code in my service looked like the following:

```
// Registration of the serviceclient in Apphost.cs:
// container.Register<IRestClient>(x => new JsonServiceClient("http://host:8080/"));
var client = ResolveService<IRestClient>();

HelloResponse response;
using (Profiler.Current.Step("RemoteService: Get Hello"))
{
   response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
}
// ... do something with response ...
```

I wanted to get rid of the `using (Profiler.Current.Step())` in this part of my code to make it easier to read and write.

```
// Registration of the serviceclient in Apphost.cs:
// container.Register<IRestClient>(x => new ProfiledRestClient("RemoteService", new JsonServiceClient("http://host:8080/")));
var client = ResolveService<IRestClient>();

HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
// ... do something with response ...
```

I made a wrapper around the existing client that contains the `Profiler.Current.Step()` code for every method of the `IRestClient` interface
 mentioning the name of the client, the method and the request(type).

```
// The implementation of the wrapper:
public class ProfiledRestClient : IRestClient
{
    readonly string clientName;
    readonly IRestClient wrappedClient;

    public ProfiledRestClient(string clientName, IRestClient wrappedClient)
    {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.wrappedClient = wrappedClient;
    }

    public TResponse Get<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> request)
    {
        using (Profiler.Current.Step("{0}: Get {1}".Fmt(clientName, request.GetType().Name)))
        {
            return wrappedClient.Get(request);
        }
    }

    public TResponse Post<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> request)
    {
        using (Profiler.Current.Step("{0}: Post {1}".Fmt(clientName, request.GetType().Name)))
        {
            return wrappedClient.Post(request);
        }
    }

    // etc. the same for all other methods of IRestClient interface
}
```

It is working but it feels a bit dirty. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you for your insight.